# F# throws warning in shadowing record type

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, record

I have 2 record types having the same signature:

```
type T1 = { a : int }
type T2 = { a : int }

let badFunc record = { record with a = 0 }
let goodFunc (record : T2) = { record with a = 0 }
```

The compiler will throw a warning in the `badFunc` function:

> The field labels and expected type of this record expression or pattern do not uniquely determine a corresponding record.

From [F# RFC FS-1025 - Improve record type inference](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/RFCs/FS-1025-improve-record-type-inference.md):

> When resolving a record type, the current behavior of the compiler is to find for each field of the record type, all the types in scope that have that field. Then it takes the intersection of those types for all the fields, and if a single matching type is found, that type is picked. Otherwise, the first type in the list is blindly chosen, and an error can ensue.

So F# should knows the `badFunc` type is `T2 -> T2`, why does F# ignore the shadowing and throw a warning instead?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't see how F sharp should know what type record has in the badFunc

Comment: @flq If `T2` is declared after `T1`, why shouldn't it be picked?

Comment: Type `T2` does not shadow `T1`, so the type is ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the record `T1` is not shadowed by the record `T2`. I can see where this reasoning might be coming from, because this is how variable shadowing works:

```
let foo () =
  let a1 = 10
  let a1 = 20
  a1
```

Here, the second declaration of `a1` hides the first one. For records, you might perhaps expect that a record with the same name will hide earlier declaration:

```
type T1 = { a : int }
type T1 = { a : int }
```

However, this does not work and you get an error message:

> error FS0037: Duplicate definition of type, exception or module 'T1'

In your definition, you are defining two separate types `T1` and `T2` and they both happen to have the same field. You can always refer to the field using the fully qualified syntax:

```
let t1Func record = { record with T1.a = 0 }
let t2Func record = { record with T2.a = 0 }
```

What should the compiler do when you write just `a`? This is a design decision - it could automatically pick one of the two, but this is generally a bit confusing because it might depend on the order in which you open namespaces. So, giving a warning, as the compiler does currently, is probably more sensible approach.